# Is it possible to convert a text to URL format using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, onsubmit, submit-button

Basically I want to know that how to build code snippet so that when a user input text and click on the submit button. Automatically add `https://` as prefix and `.com` as suffix and build a valid urls using javascript. And that result should be visible right below the form.

Can anyone help me

Comment: Provide some code what you've tried so far, explain the point where you've got stuck and need help.

Comment: Most of the time you don't want to generate an URL but verify an entered URL by a complicated regex or simply like [this](https://dev.to/calvinpak/simple-url-validation-with-javascript-4oj5).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it take input and covert it to a link by adding https:// and .com

To see it working here just type input as: **stackoverflow**. If you want to test it with other sites, copy and use the code locally.

```js
function urlMaker(){
  var linkVal=document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  var href =  document.getElementById('aLink').href="https://"+linkVal+".com";
  document.getElementById("aLink").innerHTML = href;
 }
```

```html
<input name="inputTxt" type="text" id="inputText">
<button onclick="urlMaker()">Get Link</button>
<br><br>
<a href="#" id="aLink"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate, I don't know if you know this but not all sites end with ".com" some of them might end with ".edu", ".in", ".io", ".org" etc. Also, some URLs start with "blob:https://" and things like that. I think you probably would need an API.

Comment: I know that but I am on the way of learning javascript. So it would be fine for me if any one told how to add those prefix and suffix only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you just add a `keyup` or `change` event listener on the input, and concatenate the text from the input with what you need. Here's an example:

```
// HTML
<div class="container">
    <input type="url" id="url-maker" />
    <p class="url-output"></p>
</div>
```

```
// JS
const urlInput = document.getElementById('url-maker');
const urlOutput = document.querySelector('.url-output');

urlInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    let urlText = event.target.value;
    if (!urlText.includes('https://')) {
        urlText = `https://${urlText}`;
    }
    if (!urlText.includes('.')) {
        urlText = `${urlText}.com`;
    }
    urlOutput.innerText = urlText;
});
```

However, you ***do need*** to properly validate the strings and also keep in mind that domains end in other extensions than `.com`! What I've showed you is just a basic example!

Comment: How to toggle output. No output is showing have submit button in it na??

Comment: You don't need a submit if you have `keyup` or `change` events in order to preview your URL, it will automatically appear under the input while you type, or if you leave the input field (if you use the `change` event). But you could add a button and change the event to `click` instead of `keyup`. You only need a submit button to send data to the server. Here's a [preview on CodePen](https://codepen.io/danieldogeanu/pen/poeXGWY)!